# cannot run command from puppet to update servers for puppet agent using puppet enterprise

Tags: linux, puppet, yum

I can run almost every other command via Puppet Enterprise Master to Agent, but the update command will not run. PE does run as root as far as I know.

Can someone please suggest how to get this command working on Linux from Puppet.

```
exec { "sudocmd" :
        cwd => "/usr/bin/",
        path => ["/usr/bin/","/usr/sbin/","/bin"],
    command => "yum update -y",
    timeout => "-1",
    logoutput => "on_failure",
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either run puppet agent as root (which as far as I know is a common practice) or add suid on yum to allow others to run it as root (risky!) or run "sudo yum update -y" and add your puppet agent user to sudoers without password prompt.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to better troubleshoot when running agent manually as root on the other server. It looks like maybe this is some kind of hostname/cert. issue as cert name changed and then command worked -  and not necessarily a root issue or in the way that the command was written.

Comment: specifically fqdn vs hostname on ec2 NAT instance.